# Issue with Quartz persistent jobs while using with Spring

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I have configured a spring's method invoking job previously which is working fine. Now my requirement is to have this job as persistent which will run in a clustered environment.
After configuring the quartz as clustered and persistence, application is throwing the following exception at deployment:

> java.io.NotSerializableException: Unable to serialize JobDataMap for
>   insertion into database because the value of property 'methodInvoker'
>   is not serializable:
>   org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean

I am using the following versions:

- **Spring version 3.1.4.RELEASE**
- **Quartz version 2.1.7**

**Update**: As per the documentation of `MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean`:

```
JobDetails created via this FactoryBean are not serializable.
```

So, looking for some alternative approach to configure a persistent job in spring.

Comment: Could you show your spring-quartz configuration?

Comment: What is `methodInvoker`? Is it your application property that you put into `JobDataMap`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have solved the problem by replacing `MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean` with `JobDetailFactoryBean`. Configuration for the same is as follows:

```
<bean name="myJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="mypackage.MyJob" />
    <property name="group" value="MY_JOBS_GROUP" />
    <property name="durability" value="true" />
</bean>
```

However, to `Autowire` the spring managed beans in my job class `mypackage.MyJob`, I have added the following as first line in my execute method:

```
class MyJob implements Job {
    ...
    public void execute(final JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        // Process @Autowired injection for the given target object, based on the current web application context. 
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
        ...
    }

}
```

Hope it it will help someone else facing the same issue.

Comment: Yes, it indeed work; but can we inject properties to the job class?

Answer (score 6):

When you are using persistent quartz jobs, you should be setting the `org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties` property to `true`. That forces the job data to be saved as Strings instead of Java Serialized objects.

Doing so however may cause some problems with Spring, that are easily solvable.

Check these links for more details:

http://site.trimplement.com/using-spring-and-quartz-with-jobstore-properties/

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/121806-quartz-error-ioexception

Answer (score 0):

The other way to solve this problem is avoid using 'jobDataMap' property for 'JobDetailFactoryBean' bean. Instead, add the dependency (the bean containing method to run) in Scheudler with 'schedulerContextAsMap' property.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
     ... (other properties)...
     <property name="schedulerContextAsMap">
     <map>
       <entry key="executeProcessBean" value-ref="executeProcessBean" />
     </map>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Since, the documentation of schedulerContextAsMap in SchedulerFactoryBean mentions about the usage when you have Spring beans.

```
/**
     * Register objects in the Scheduler context via a given Map.
     * These objects will be available to any Job that runs in this Scheduler.
     * <p>Note: When using persistent Jobs whose JobDetail will be kept in the
     * database, do not put Spring-managed beans or an ApplicationContext
     * reference into the JobDataMap but rather into the SchedulerContext.
     * @param schedulerContextAsMap Map with String keys and any objects as
     * values (for example Spring-managed beans)
     * @see JobDetailFactoryBean#setJobDataAsMap
     */
```

Answer (score 0):

just add  `implements Serializable`

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.